# Displaying MYSQL SELECT result in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am attempting to echo the result of a query into a text area where the noteID = 1. However, I am receiving this error message:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_get_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 81.

Why is this when that row does in fact exist?

```
<?php
    require 'znotseen-database-connection.php';
    $sql = "SELECT noteText FROM notes WHERE noteID = 1";
    $test = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($test);
    echo($result);
```

Comment: Take a look at the type returned by [mysqli_stmt_get_results](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

- `mysqli_query()` returns an object of class `mysqli_result`
- `mysqli_stmt_get_result()` accepts a parameter of type `mysqli_stmt` and returns an object of `mysqli_result`

**You can't mix them together!**

You should be using prepared statements or static queries.

If you use static queries then you can just use the result of `mysqli_query` in a loop.

```
<?php
require 'znotseen-database-connection.php';
$sql = "SELECT noteText FROM notes WHERE noteID = 1";
$test = $conn->query($sql);

foreach($test as $row) {
    echo $row['noteText'];
}
```

If your query has parameters then you need to use prepared statements. After executing it you need to call `get_result()` to fetch the data into PHP from MySQL.

```
<?php
require 'znotseen-database-connection.php';

$id = 1;
$sql = "SELECT noteText FROM notes WHERE noteID = ?";
$test = $conn->prepare($sql);
$test->bind_param('s', $id);
$test->execute();
$result = $test->get_result();

foreach($test as $row) {
    echo $row['noteText'];
}
```